# Finish input into JEditorPane on ENTER

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-platform

I am using a JEditorPane as a component to show code. The JEditorPane resides in my custom PropertyEditorSupport for my Netbeans Platform app and is show in an OutlineView and the Properties window.

I've already limited the JEditorPane to be one line only, using a DocumentFilter. However I am not able to rebuild the funcionality a JTextField has, to finish input into the component by hitting the ENTER key.

I have already thought about adding a KeyListener event to my JEditorPane but am not sure what to do in case of the event. Is there a method to be called to "finish input of text"?

Answer (score 0):

> I am using a JEditorPane as a component to show code.
>   I've already limited the JEditorPane to be one line only

Those two statements seems to contradict one another. Usually codes consists of multiple lines, not one line.

In any case if you are simply display text then I would use a JTextPane as it supports text attributes. A JEditorPane is used to display HTML.

> I have already thought about adding a KeyListener event

Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`. Basically you create an `Action` (in your case you would extend `TextAction`) and you bind the `Action` to a `KeyStroke`. Check out [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) which contains more information as well as a link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Key Bindings`.

Comment: I am using a JEditorPane because of it's ability to have a content type. This enables me to register my custom syntax highlighting inside Netbeans for this content type. 
I agree with you, that could is normally more than one line long. In my use case, we only use the JEditorPane to enter a simple line of code to provide a quick way to configure something.

Comment: @padde, well the JEditorPane was a side issue, the Key Bindings answers your question about handling the Enter key.